# How to make an a files contents and name increment by +1 a certain number of times

Tags: autoit, basic

I'm currently trying to build the frame for a AutoIT script i'll be using to save a certain number of files with very small changes to them a certain number of times basically something like:

User inserts how many files they want.

Notepad opens and writes File1.

Automatically saves as File1.txt

Notepad writes File2.

Automatically saves as File2.txt.

And so on.

I've been able to figure this out in pywinauto however when I tried to apply it to the actual program I wanted to use it on I couldn't get it to identify the necessary areas to edit. So now I'm attempting it in AutoIT which I have absolutely no experience in.

This is what I have so far:

```
$NumVar = 0
Run('Notepad')
WinWait('Untitled - Notepad')
While ($NumVar < 5)
    ;Run('Notepad')
    ;WinWait('Untitled - Notepad')
    Send('File' & $NumVar)

    Send('^s')
    WinWaitActive("Save As")
    Send("test" & $NumVar & ".txt")
    Send("{ENTER}")
    WinActivate("test" & $NumVar)
    $NumVar = $NumVar + 1

    ;WinWaitActive("test" & $NumVar & "- Notepad")
WEnd
($NumVar > 5)
```

This works for the first file however after that I get something like

"File0

fFFFiiiilllelee3e42s!SFile4"

printed to notepad.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should try doing it once without the loop and go through each step. For example. One of the first things you do is run notepad. After that you go into a loop and run notepad again.

Comment: Why do you use Send and Run instead of native AutoIt-Functions for creating files? Take a look on `FileWrite` / `FileRead` https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Script is incorrect, but you can discover details and fix issues using simple debug techniques:

- Put delays into script with [Sleep()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Sleep.htm), so you can see each step performed one by one instead of rapid flickering on the screen
- Use [_DebugOut()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_DebugOut.htm) to print comments, so you know, which step is being executed.

Current script logic isn't OK:

- Open notepad
- Type `File0` and hit `ctrl+s`. "Save as" dialog appears.
- Type `test0.txt` and hit enter. Your file is saved now into "test0.txt", notepad's title changes to file name, file content is shown in notepad.
- Now things go bad way. Script starts loop from the beginning: it types `File1`, which is appended to `File0` text.
- Hit `ctrl+s` doesn't force "save as" dialog. Notepad already knows, that "test0.txt" is being edited, so "test0.txt" is simply saved with `File0File1`
- Script waits for activation "save as" dialog, but it never happens, so script waits forever.
- You can kill stuck script from tray icon, but you seems to launch second instance of script instead, so they start interfering. Once second instance opens "save as" dialog, the both instances print text into it resulting into mess.

So you expectations of notepad state are wrong, that's the cause.

One important note: using text editors directly for file operation isn't the easiest nor the most reliable way to work. You should look into [FileWrite()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWrite.htm) which is much more convenient.